# StatefulElement#00113(DEFUNCT)(no widget)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm passing a **context** to a method and then using a Bloc instance.

```
static void cleanUserData(BuildContext context){
   BlocProvider.of<ProfileBloc>(context).add(Event());
}
```

Sometimes it works correctly and sometimes it is not.

I see the **context** and its value is:

```
StatefulElement#00113(DEFUNCT)(no widget)
```

Probably the problem is because of **context** but I don't know why it is wrong.

Comment: Please share the full code like where you are calling the cleanUserData and from where is the context being passed from.

Comment: Did you get any warning or error in Debug Console? paste it here

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.